# HTML5 video: ffmpeg-encoded MP4 not playing in any browser (plays in VLC though)

Tags: google-chrome, cross-browser, html5-video, mp4, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to serve HTML5 video in MP4 and WEBM fomats.  I cannot get all browsers to work though:

- Browsers which support WEBM (Chrome desktop, Firefox desktop) play the videos fine.
- Browsers which use MP4 are not working (IE, Safari, Android).
- WEBM is being served as `video/webm`.
- MP4 is being served as `video/mp4`.

Minimal JSFiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=5Ql5MmrV4j

---

#### Browser errors:

- IE11: 11.0.9600.17126 / 11.0.9 KB2957689

  `Error: Unsupported video type of invalid file path`
- Android browser and Chrome Android:

  No error, video just refuses to start

---

#### Sanity test - the following three values are equal:

- Received file size: `curl <video URL> | wc -c`
- Actual file size: `stat -c %s <video file>`
- Server-specified file size: `Content-Length` HTTP header.

---

#### One of the videos in question is at:

- **MP4**: http://hackology.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/hd720-24.mp4

  `Content-Type: video/mp4`

  Does not play in Chrome / IE11 / Chrome Android / Android Browser

  Does play in VLC

  FFMPEG encoding parameters:

  `-an -vcodec libx264 -s hd720
  -flags +loop+mv4
  -cmp 256
  -partitions +parti4x4+parti8x8+partp4x4+partp8x8
  -subq 6 -trellis 0 -refs 5 -bf 0 -coder 0 -me_range 16 -g 250
  -keyint_min 25 -sc_threshold 40 -i_qfactor 0.71
  -qmin 10 -qmax 51 -qdiff 4
  -movflags faststart`

  These were collected from deep searching on the best way to encode MP4 for mobile browsers.
  If I use `-an -vcodec libx264 -s hd720` then that video also doesn't work in browsers.
- **WEBM**: http://hackology.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/hd720-24.webm

  `Content-Type: video/webm`

  Plays in Chrome/Firefox

  FFMPEG encoding parameters:

  `-an -vcodec libvpx -s hd720`

---

#### The relevant HTML (classes, poster, etc removed):

```
<video preload="metadata" controls="controls">
  <source type="video/mp4" src="http://hackology.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/hd720-24.mp4">
  <source type="video/webm" src="http://hackology.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/hd720-24.webm">
</video>
```

JSFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=5Ql5MmrV4j

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No MP4-playing browsers actually seem to have full support for MP4 - especially problematic for MS and Apple's browsers which are trying to create a royalty-hell / monopoly around the format.

I got it to work by re-encoding with the following FFMPEG parameters:

```
-pix_fmt yuv420p
-preset slow
-profile:v baseline
```

Giving a full command line of:

```
ffmpeg
  <INPUT DEFINITION>    # e.g. -i <FILE>
  -an    # if you won't want audio, otherwise -acodec libaac -b:a 128k
  -s hd720
  -vcodec libx264
  -b:v BITRATE    # e.g. 4M
  -vcodec libx264
  -pix_fmt yuv420p
  -preset slow
  -profile:v baseline
  -movflags faststart
  -y <OUTPUT PATH>
```

The problem was ultimately yet another example of proprietary software vendors not properly supporting their own standards.

Comment: Hey there, I know it's been a time since you've "fixed" this problem, but unfortunately I've got the same problem now, my ffmpeg command was: 

ffmpeg -i inputfile -b:v 2500k -vcodec libx264 -vprofile main -acodec livbo_aacenc -b_a 128k output

would be awesome if you could help me.

Comment: Use baseline profile and yuv420p subsampling,  and mp3 audio codec

Comment: Apparently `-level 3.0` also helps, but I've never needed it