# Firefox and Chrome can't play HTML5 mp4 video

Tags: html, firefox, video, mp4

I have an HTML page that contains a MP4 video:

```
<html>
<body>

<video width="800" height="600" controls>
  <source src="/static/xyz.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <p>Your browser does not support the video tag.</p>
</video>

</body>
</html>
```

When I load the page in Firefox, it doesn't show the play control buttons but shows error message "No video with supported format and MIME type found" (see the screenshot below).

[image: Screenshot of Firefox when playing video]

So I use [this site](http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/tests/video.html) to test my browser's ability to play HTML5 mp4 video and it can successfully play the test video on that site. My Firefox version is v36 on CentOS Linux. I also tried using Chrome and it can't play it either. I also tried it on Firefox/Chrome on Windows but failed. I then use the Firefox debugger to look at the debug info and I see the following message:

```
Media resource http://localhost:5000/static/xyz.mp4 could not be decoded.
All candidate resources failed to load. Media load paused.
```

I then tried playing the xyz.mp4 video on my local machine using Linux's movie player and it plays fine and it also plays fine in Window's media player. But when I use the above HTML5 `<video>` tag, it doesn't play for all browsers in both Linux and Windows. I also followed Mozilla's online forum to change the browser settings and clear caches but none of them works. So what caused the problem of this simple HTML5 ?

Answer (score 2):

This is very likely the problem with your video file. mp4 is not really a format, but a container that can hold video in different formats. Firefox supports only H.264 encoded video.

Simply speaking, there are several types of mp4 files and not all of them are supported by browser. To verify this, you can download one of the videos from the quicksmode website and replace your video with it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried using the video downloaded from quicksmode website and replace my video with that and it can play in my browser. So you're right, it must be related to my video itself. But I generated xyz.mp4 video by using Python call `anim.save('xyz.mp4', writer = FFwriter, fps=100, extra_args=['-vcodec', 'libx264'])`. I installed libffmpeg and I assume that it is encoded by H.264 codec since the last arg is libx264, Isn't it?

Comment: Browsers only support baseline h264, but your encoder might have different preset by default. This SO answer can help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24693751/html5-video-ffmpeg-encoded-mp4-not-playing-in-any-browser-plays-in-vlc-though

Comment: I solved the problem after I corrected the writer used to generate the mp4. I should have used 'ffmpeg' as the writer directly.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:

```
  //autoplay muted onloadedmetadata="this.muted = true"  

<video id="abc" autoplay muted onloadedmetadata="this.muted = true" >
  <source src="https://github.com/mediaelement/mediaelement-files/blob/master/big_buck_bunny.mp4?raw=true" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```